# Can't show CBR pages

Tags: 14.04, evince

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to open some CBR files. First I tried with evince. While I was using Ubuntu 13.10 at different installation I can open with evince. After trying with evince, I installed Comix. Following screenshot shows when I open file with Comix. I can read this file without any problem on my android tablet.[image: Comix]

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why it's not working with Comix but getting it to work with Evince is quite easy. In my opinion, Evince is superior to Comix. To get cbr files to open with Evince, all you have to do is install Unrar. To install Unrar, enter the following command in the terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends unrar
```

After installing Unrar, you should be able to open cbr files (and other comic book files) with Evince. You don't have to change any settings, just install Unrar.

Comment: It gives **unrar is already installed** error.

Comment: its not an error.

Answer (score 0):

Using comix and installing unrar worked for me